# afterTransactionCompletion() was never called

Tags: hibernate, transactions

hi when i run my application using hibernate to insert in database sql 5.0 i get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.domain.projet.config.Facade.createConnexion(Facade.java:227)     at org.domain.projet.config.Test.main(Test.java:49) 5 mai 2011 10:41:27 net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl finalize

this is the method:

```
public Connexion createConnexion( int id_utilisateur) throws HibernateException
{
    Connexion con =new Connexion();
    con.setDateDeb(new Date());
    con.setDateFin(new Date());
    con.setIdCnx(id_utilisateur);


        Session session = sessFactory.openSession();
         net.sf.hibernate.Transaction tx=null;
       try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Utilisateur user=(Utilisateur) session.load(Utilisateur.class,id_utilisateur);
    con.setUtil(user);
    //((List<Connexion>)user.getConnexions()).add((Connexion) con);
    user.getConnexions().add(con);
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    session.saveOrUpdate(con);

    //session.flush();
      tx.commit();
        }
      catch (HibernateException he) {

             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
           throw he;

         }
        finally {
         session.close();
         }
return con;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace tells you exactly where the error lies : at line 227, in the class `Facade`, and in the method `createConnexion`. At this line, you probably call a method on a null reference. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to be more precise.

BTW : what's the relation between the title and the body of your question?